# how to compile C++ code through terminal

Tags: c++, macos, file, compilation, terminal

I am using the atom text editor. I want to compile a simple "hello world" program using the osx terminal (yosemite version 10.10.4). I named the program ctut.cpp.
So, then on the terminal I wrote the command `g++ ctut.cpp`
but ended up getting

> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ctut.cpp'
>
> clang: error: no input files

why is it saying the file does not exist?

Comment: did you `cd` to the directory where `ctut.php` is ?

Comment: @Raptor .php?, lol, it was great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the file's path if it is not in your home directory. If your file is inside a directory named `Code` inside the `Home` directory, then you need to do `g++ ~/Code/ctut.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to cd into the directory where you saved ctut.cpp or use the files path as explained in chintan's answer although your also not typing the full command. It should be `g++ ctut.cpp -o ctut` then to run the program you type `./ctut`